# Dates before Jan. 01 1970?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to write a javascript function that calculates the time since Oct 11th, 1910 so I can throw it into a timer for a project I'm working on. I get that javascript's milliseconds works from epoc, but I don't and can't find a way to get the milliseconds since a date earlier than 01.01.1970

Does anyone have any loose code that can do the above that they may be willing to share?

Comment: Aren't negative values before Jan 1 1970?

Comment: Any date before that Unix epoq seems to give a NaN value.
ex : new Date("333-02-06T06:00:00") ==> Nan

This is a problem for time processing in astronomy applications for dates before 1970...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```js
var oldGoodTimes = new Date(1910, 9, 11); // January = 0
var actualDate = new Date();
console.log(actualDate.getTime() - oldGoodTimes.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
var yeOldeTimes = new Date();
yeOldeTimes.setFullYear(1910, 9, 11);

var myNewDate = new Date();
console.log("Milliseconds since Ye Olde Times: " + (myNewDate - yeOldeTimes));
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of milliseconds since Oct 11th, 1910

```js
console.log(new Date() - new Date('1910', '10', '11'))

// new Date().valueOf() - milliseconds since 1970
// -(new Date('1910', '10', '11')).valueOf() - milliseconds from 1910 since 1970
```